# Create thumnail for video and play video on click

Tags: ios, iphone, video, scrollview

i am new to ios,I want to create thumnail for videos in horizontal view.After tapping on thumnail video should paly.I have created custum player but unable to create horizontal thgumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create thumbnail of video using bellow code:

```
-(UIImage *)getThumbNail:(NSString*)stringPath   // string path is a path of you video file
{
    NSURL *urlvideoImage =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:urlvideoImage options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generateImg = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 65);
    CGImageRef refImg = [generateImg copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&error];
    NSLog(@"error==%@, Refimage==%@", error, refImg);

    UIImage *FrameImage= [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:refImg];


//   
    return FrameImage;
}
```

- Create thumbnail from your video URL using above code.
- Set this Image as a button background Image or you can use Image View and set Tap-gesture forget it's touch event.
- By click on Button you can Play video with relevant code. Hope that is working for you.

Comment: Thanks i got the thumnail,but image dosenot fit to my imageview.i have used this code:-[scrollView Alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _movieView.bounds.size.width, _movieView.bounds.size.height)]

Comment: set image view contain mode:  yourImageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;